# ExchangeConnectionMode is olNoExchange (0) when Outlook is not open

Tags: vba, windows, outlook

On one PC using Excel VBA and Outlook `ExchangeConnectionMode` results in `0` which means it is not connected to Exchange while Outlook is closed. We use Office 365 on a recent Windows 10 Version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/outlook.account.exchangeconnectionmode

I assume there is an option in Outlook to keep Exchange connected when Outlook is not open.

```vb
Set myApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
MsgBox(myNameSpace.ExchangeConnectionMode) ' returns 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure it out actually. As i expected it had to do with the account settings. In it, you need to have "Use Cached Exchange Mode" enabled. With having it enabled it returns to mode `400` which will allow accessing cached mails

[image]